# HTML5 application with webservice using phonegap, doesn't work properly on android device

Tags: android, html, cordova, jsonp

I have created HTML5 application based on web services(JSON) . Using Phonegap files I have tried to implement it on android. While running on Android tablet device, I went through following scenarios 
i. When click on 'A' tab it opens A tab with layout but without data (data will come from Web service)
ii. After this click on some other tab and then use device BACK button then only it displays all data of 'A' tab

One more thing, this application runs perfectly on Emulator and Browser.